# What is the point of setting setInterruptIfStopped to true in a JobIntentService?

Tags: android, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler, jobservice, jobintentservice

JobIntentService has the `setInterruptIfStopped` method which, when set to `true`, causes the currently running `AsyncTask` to `cancel` if the job is stopped:

> void setInterruptIfStopped (boolean interruptIfStopped)
>
> Control whether code executing in onHandleWork(Intent) will be interrupted if the job is stopped. By default this is false. If called and set to true, any time onStopCurrentWork() is called, the class will first call AsyncTask.cancel(true) to interrupt the running task.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService

However, this doesn't actually interrupt the work running in `onHandleWork`. Instead, this just sets a `boolean` in the `AsyncTask` to `true`, which I would need to check for in `onHandleWork` to interrupt my work manually.

> public final boolean isCancelled ()
>
> Returns true if this task was cancelled before it completed normally. If you are calling cancel(boolean) on the task, the value returned by this method should be checked periodically from doInBackground(Object[]) to end the task as soon as possible.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

But for this we already have the `JobIntentService`'s `isStopped` method:

> boolean isStopped ()
>
> Returns true if onStopCurrentWork() has been called. You can use this, while executing your work, to see if it should be stopped.

From my understanding, we can't even access the `AsyncTask`'s `isCancelled` method.
So what is the use of `setInterruptIfStopped` in `JobIntentService`?